# Workflows C#, how to break out of execution

Tags: c#, workflow

At the  moment I am using fault handlers to break out of execution e.g:

State1:
HandleExternalEvent
 -> MyCode (possibly throw exception)
 -> Change state2

->Fault handler
 ->no code (i.e stays in state1)

However I am suffering from a performace hit, is there away to perform the same action without using exceptions/fault handle, like a cancel or return method

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify MyCode is a custom activity I implemented, I had a little success with (in the activity) with:

test.Parent.dispose();

However the action seems to be delayed and not reliable; sometimes it will prevent further execution of the parent activity whilst other times it will continue onwards

Is there a more reliable way to end the parent activity execution and go back to idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SuspendActivity to pause a workflow, and then maybe interact with it later through a ReceiveActivity or something similar.